# Как сделать Uptime?

Tags: python

Как сделать uptime в python 3.6 что бы выводил время так:

```
print("Я работаю уже 0 дней 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Что именно вызывает вопросы - как считать время или как форматировать вывод?

Comment: как считать время и как форматировать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переносимый способ с помощью [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil

uptime = lambda start=psutil.boot_time(): time.time() - start
```

`uptime()` возвращает количество секунд с загрузки компьютера, определяемого по Unix времени. Эта величина может быть немонотонной при изменении времени на компьютере, к примеру, с помощью ntp поправок (или около високосных секунд).